# Unity Nav Mesh instantiation Issue

Tags: unity, navmesh

I've been working on a wave-based zombie game for the past few months and all of the systems have been working perfectly - until I upgraded to the latest version of Unity. Since then, spawning a zombie onto a nav mesh and then calling SetDesination is throwing the exception:

```
"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.
UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)
```

The zombies are spawned a random spawn point and their destination set as so:

```
 GameObject go;
        for (int i = 0; i < SpawnAmount; i++)
        {
            Vector3 location = new Vector3(transform.position.x + i + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), transform.position.y, transform.position.z + i + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));
            go = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, location, spawnRotation) as GameObject;
            go.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().SetDestination(players[0].transform.position);
        }
```

It is the setdestination line that is causing me issues.

I have a static baked nav area. The player characters (who also use nav agent to move) can move across the nav area perfectly - it is only the zombies which seem to have trouble.

I have spent a long while tweaking settings here and there. Adjusting the location of the zombie and even having a zombie in the game before starting the game. However I can't seem to correct this exception - all while the player characters are moving perfectly.

Any ideas on what I could be missing or areas I should be looking?

[image: A spawned zombie with its nav agent details]

[image: The nav mesh]

[image: Nav mesh agent settings]

EDIT The updated and working code:

```
GameObject go;
for (int i = 0; i < SpawnAmount; i++)
{
    Vector3 location = new Vector3(transform.position.x + i + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), transform.position.y, transform.position.z + i + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));
    go = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, location, spawnRotation) as GameObject;
    go.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().Warp(location);
    go.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().SetDestination(players[0].transform.position);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here but I think that if you set a agents position with transform.position it does not know it's on the nav mesh. try using `NavMeshAgent.Warp(spawnPosition)` after you instantiate the zombie and the set its destination.

Comment: Thanks for that. Worked like a treat! Not sure what changed between the Unity versions but glad it's working. 
Updated code in main post